# How to plot complicated expressions in Octave?

Tags: plot, octave

I am wondering if there is a way to plot a complicated equation in Octave.

For instance: x + xy + (x^2)*y + x*(y^3) = 3

Is there a way...?

Thank you...!

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Is this your homework? Please try to show what you have attempted and where the difficulty is for you. You'll learn much more if you attempt to do your own homework. This is what homework is for!

Comment: It's not homework but I totally get what you mean. I tried a naive exhaustive computing for finding y at each x, but I noticed that for this equation, a single x can have multiple y values...

Comment: I recommend looking up the function ezplot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, there is. According to the [ezplot Function Reference](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/ezplot.html), the solution is quite direct, actually. Note that you'll need to **pass that "3"** from the right side of the equation **to the left side**. For instance, in your example, the following code should work:

```
ezplot (inline ("x + x*y + (x^2)*y + x*(y^3) - 3"));
```